# ¿ Como arreglar mi menú de navegación?

Tags: html, web, menú

Estoy tratando de crear una humilde web la cual consta de cabecera y ASIDE izquierdo y ASIDE derecho, los cuales funcionan pero al añadir los siguientes estilos css y librerias javascript, dejan de verse correctamente: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` Con una barra de navegación con tres elementos, uno de los cuales tiene a su vez tres desplegables, que con estos enlaces  funcionan. Otro problema del menú de navegación de la cabecera me pone trabas. Quiero un menú como en 
en el siguiente link:[https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp][1] 
Lo tengo como la muestro en el código, y el menú se queda verticalmente , cuando debería estar horizontal.
Pero cuando le agrego [https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css][1], funciona el menú, pero se estropea el resto de la pagina.
Bueno, mi consulta seria si hay forma de solucionarlo con lo que tengo, cual son los errores que estoy cometiendo ?
Espero haberme expresado lo suficientemente bien para que entiendan los problemas que no consigo corregir del menú de navegación, conseguir el menú horizontal y la lista desplegable pinchando en uno de los elementos del este menú.
Muchas gracias y un saludo.
Muestro mi codigo.

```css
<style type="text/css">
    
            /* Layout */
            body {
                min-width: 630px;
            }
    
            #container {
                padding-left: 200px;
                padding-right: 190px;
            }
            
            #container .column {
                position: relative;
                float: left;
            }
            
            #center {
                padding: 10px 20px;
                width: 100%;
            }
            
            #left {
                width: 180px;
                padding: 0 10px;
                right: 240px;
                margin-left: -100%;
            }
            
            #right {
                width: 130px;
                padding: 0 10px;
                margin-right: -100%;
            }
            
            #footer {
                clear: both;
            }
            
            /* IE hack */
            * html #left {
                left: 150px;
            }
    
            /* Make the columns the same height as each other */
            #container {
                overflow: hidden;
            }
    
            #container .column {
                padding-bottom: 1001em;
                margin-bottom: -1000em;
            }
    
            /* Fix for the footer */
            * html body {
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            
            * html #footer-wrapper {
                float: left;
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
                padding-bottom: 10010px;
                margin-bottom: -10000px;
                background: #fff;
            }
    
            /* Aesthetics */
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                font-family:Sans-serif;
                line-height: 1.5em;
            }
            
            p {
                color: #555;
            }
    
            nav ul {
                list-style-type: none;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            
            nav ul a {
                color: darkgreen;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
    
            #header, #footer {
                font-size: large;
                padding: 0.3em;
                background: #BCCE98;
            }
    
            #left {
                background: #DAE9BC;
            }
            
            #right {
                background: #F7FDEB;
            }
    
            #center {
                background: #fff;
            }
    
            #container .column {
                padding-top: 1em;
            }
            
        </style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">-->
    <link rel="icon" href="imagenes/icon.ico" />
    
    <!--SI AÑADO LA SIGUIENTE API (https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css) , FUNCIONA EL MENU DE NAVEGACION PERO ESTROPEA EL RESTO DE PAGINA-->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <style type="text/css">
    
            /* Layout */
            body {
                min-width: 630px;
            }
    
            #container {
                padding-left: 200px;
                padding-right: 190px;
            }
            
            #container .column {
                position: relative;
                float: left;
            }
            
            #center {
                padding: 10px 20px;
                width: 100%;
            }
            
            #left {
                width: 180px;
                padding: 0 10px;
                right: 240px;
                margin-left: -100%;
            }
            
            #right {
                width: 130px;
                padding: 0 10px;
                margin-right: -100%;
            }
            
            #footer {
                clear: both;
            }
            
            /* IE hack */
            * html #left {
                left: 150px;
            }
    
            /* Make the columns the same height as each other */
            #container {
                overflow: hidden;
            }
    
            #container .column {
                padding-bottom: 1001em;
                margin-bottom: -1000em;
            }
    
            /* Fix for the footer */
            * html body {
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            
            * html #footer-wrapper {
                float: left;
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
                padding-bottom: 10010px;
                margin-bottom: -10000px;
                background: #fff;
            }
    
            /* Aesthetics */
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                font-family:Sans-serif;
                line-height: 1.5em;
            }
            
            p {
                color: #555;
            }
    
            nav ul {
                list-style-type: none;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            
            nav ul a {
                color: darkgreen;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
    
            #header, #footer {
                font-size: large;
                padding: 0.3em;
                background: #BCCE98;
            }
    
            #left {
                background: #DAE9BC;
            }
            
            #right {
                background: #F7FDEB;
            }
    
            #center {
                background: #fff;
            }
    
            #container .column {
                padding-top: 1em;
            }
            
        </style>
    <title>Principal</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
        <header id="header">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Logo and responsive toggle -->
                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> 
                        Logo
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- Navbar links -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#">Principal</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Sobre mi</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Estudios</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Recursos <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="about-us">
                                <li><a href="#">Productos</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Juegos</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Diseño</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
    
                    <!-- Search -->
                    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
                    </form>
    
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container -->
        </nav>
    </header>
        <div id="container">
    
            <main id="center" class="column">
                <article>
                
                    <h1>BIENVENIDOS A MI SITIO WEB...</h1>
                    <p>Hola, me llamo Miguel y os voy a presentar mi sitio web,
                     En principio esta creado para mostrar mi perfil, experiencia laboral, formación académica y todos los conocimientos </p>
                            
                    
                    <P></P>
                    <h2>CURRICULUM</h2>
                    <p>Aquí encontrareis los <a href="curriculum-1.html">trabajos </a>por los que me he movido, siendo el transporte por carretera lo que mas he desempeñado estos 
                            últimos años. </p>
                    <h2></h2>
                    <h2>ESPEDIENTE ACADEMICO</h2>
                    <p>Mis estudios no son muchos, deje pronto la escuela para trabajar. Pero en los últimos años he retomado el tema académico,
                            formandome en el tema de la programación y aunque llevo poco tiempo ya he creado alguna <a href="proyectos-4.html">humilde aplicacion.</a></p>
                    
                    <h2>EXPERIENCIA</h2>

                    <p>Como ya he dicho, mi carrera de desarrollador no a echo mas que empezar, y son pocos y pequeños los <a href="proyectos-4.html">proyectos </a>que he 

                    </p>
                    <h2></h2>
                    <h2></h2>
            

                        
                    <a href="pdf/html.pdf">Haz clic aquí para el PDF</a>
                    <object  data="pdf/html.pdf"></object>
                    
                    <iframe  src="pdf/html.pdf"></iframe>
                   
                  
                
                </article>        
            </main>
    
            <nav id="left" class="column">
                <h3>DATOS PERSONALES</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="curriculum-1.html">Curriculum</a></li><br>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="estudios-2.html">Estudios</a></li><br>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="experiencia-3.html">Experiencia</a></li><br>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="proyectos-4.html">Proyectos</a></li><br>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="futuro-5.html">Futuro</a></li>

                </ul>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
              
                <h3>Redes sociales</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100009248037432">Facebook</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://twitter.com/laparramiguel">Twitter</a></li>
                    <!--<li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>-->
                </ul>
    
            </nav>
    
            <div id="right" class="column">
                <h3>FOTO DE PERFIL</h3>
                
            </div>
    
        </div>
    
       <!-- <div id="footer-wrapper">
            <footer id="footer"><p>Footer...</p></footer>
        </div>-->
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: ¿Ya agregaste el archivo JavaScript de Bootstrap? Me parece que no se ve correctamente por lo mismo. Bootstrap se compone de dos archivos principalmente, un archivo CSS (mismo que ya agregaste), y un archivo JavaScript que agrega las animaciones, adicionalmente utiliza jQuery. Aqui te dejo un link que puede ayudarte: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo. La cosa es que de momento no he arrimado javascript, porque estoy creando. No entiendo para que me hace falta javascript si aun no tengo acciones que realizar.

Comment: No hay otra forma de solucionar, esa pagina esta solo en un archivo y no tiene funcion alguna...???

Comment: Dame un momento, ya te escribo una respuesta :)

Comment: El JavaScript es un componente necesario de Bootstrap para la animación y varias funciones mismas del framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problemas está en que no estás "llamando" a los componentes básicos de Bootstrap, de modo que no se hace la animación de forma correcta. Aquí te muestro tu código corregido, pon atención en el `<link>` y los dos `<script>` que se añaden en la cabecera del archivo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">-->
    <link rel="icon" href="imagenes/icon.ico" />
    <head>
    <!--SI AÑADO LA SIGUIENTE API (https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css) , FUNCIONA EL MENU DE NAVEGACION PERO ESTROPEA EL RESTO DE PAGINA-->
    <!--<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Principal</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
        <header id="header">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Logo and responsive toggle -->
                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> 
                        Logo
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- Navbar links -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#">Principal</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Sobre mi</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Estudios</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Recursos<span class="caret"></span></a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                  <li><a href="#">Prodcutos</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">Juegos</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">Diseño</a></li>
                             </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- Search -->
                    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Buscar</button>
                    </form>
    
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container -->
        </nav>
    </header>
        <div id="container">
    
            <main id="center" class="column">
                <article>
                
                    <h1>BIENVENIDOS A MI SITIO WEB...</h1>
                    <p>Hola, me llamo Miguel y os voy a presentar mi sitio web,
                     En principio esta creado para mostrar mi perfil, experiencia laboral, formación académica y todos los conocimientos </p>
                            
                    
                    <P></P>
                    <h2>CURRICULUM</h2>
                    <p>Aquí encontrareis los <a href="curriculum-1.html">trabajos </a>por los que me he movido, siendo el transporte por carretera lo que mas he desempeñado estos 
                            últimos años. </p>
                    <h2></h2>
                    <h2>ESPEDIENTE ACADEMICO</h2>
                    <p>Mis estudios no son muchos, deje pronto la escuela para trabajar. Pero en los últimos años he retomado el tema académico,
                            formandome en el tema de la programación y aunque llevo poco tiempo ya he creado alguna <a href="proyectos-4.html">humilde aplicacion.</a></p>
                    
                    <h2>EXPERIENCIA</h2>

                    <p>Como ya he dicho, mi carrera de desarrollador no a echo mas que empezar, y son pocos y pequeños los <a href="proyectos-4.html">proyectos </a>que he 

                    </p>
                    <h2></h2>
                    <h2></h2>
            

                        
                    <a href="pdf/html.pdf">Haz clic aquí para el PDF</a>
                    <object  data="pdf/html.pdf"></object>
                    
                    <iframe  src="pdf/html.pdf"></iframe>
                   
                  
                
                </article>        
            </main>
    
            <nav id="left" class="column">
                <h3>DATOS PERSONALES</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="curriculum-1.html">Curriculum</a></li><br>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="estudios-2.html">Estudios</a></li><br>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="experiencia-3.html">Experiencia</a></li><br>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="proyectos-4.html">Proyectos</a></li><br>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="futuro-5.html">Futuro</a></li>

                </ul>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
              
                <h3>Redes sociales</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100009248037432">Facebook</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://twitter.com/laparramiguel">Twitter</a></li>
                    <!--<li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>-->
                </ul>
    
            </nav>
    
            <div id="right" class="column">
                <h3>FOTO DE PERFIL</h3>
                
            </div>
    
        </div>
    
       <!-- <div id="footer-wrapper">
            <footer id="footer"><p>Footer...</p></footer>
        </div>-->
    
    </body>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    </html>
```

Espero te sirva :)

Comment: Perfecto,ahora funciona. Pero he cometido un error al formular la pregunta y otro al poner el codigo, pues el css no esta enlazado, ya que en mi documento lo tengo en linea.

Comment: Voy a editarlo pues la pagina consta de la cabecera y dos aside, uno izquierda y otro en la derecha. Perdona por el error, lo que tu me has propuesto funciona perfectamente. Gracias

Comment: No importa donde tengas alojado tu documento HTML, los `<script>` y `<link>` están apuntando a un servidor en línea, de modo que se verán bien en cualquier lugar que se visualice. Ahora bien, veo que tienes clases CSS en la cabecera, te recomiendo utilizar las clases de bootstrap `class="text-center"`, por ejemplo para alinear el texto al centro.

Comment: Edite el codigo para añadir el css, pues al añadir bootstrap, me elimina los laterales. Y te quite el voto sin querer ya no me deja devolverlo.

Comment: @Miguel: si reconoces que esta respuesta respondió correctamente a tu pregunta original, lo correcto es aceptar este respuesta. Si tu intención era hacer otra pregunta, en vez de modificar esta pregunta e invalidar la respuesta ya existente, lo mejor es abrir una nueva pregunta.

Comment: @sstan Hola, perdona, ya hize alguna pregunta despues de esta, y si me fue util esta respuesta, olvide marcar como tal, ahora lo hago, Gracias por su perspicacia.